# React unable to update props

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-state

So, I have a file called `Columns.js` which has a following code:

```
const cols = {
key1:val1,
key2:val2,
...
...
}
export default cols;
```

Now, I have another file called `Widget.js` which has following code:

```
//other imports 
import cols from './Columns';
//import Table and TableLoader

export default function Widget(){
const data,error,loading... = useQuery(//some query)
if(loading)return (<TableLoader cols={cols}/>);
return (<Table cols={cols} data={data}/>)
}
```

I am using react-table
Now, Look how TableLoader works:

```
cols.map((col)=>col.Cell = (<SomeComponent />);
//look here I am calling Table
return <Table cols={cols} data={[{}]}>
```

Now, issue is that since `cols` get updated in the Loader, when the loading is complete and am passing the cols in  in `Widget.js`, I am getting the cols with updated ones. Any idea how to tackle this? I want to the previous unchanged cols.

Note: Cloning it using spread operator is what I have tried, doesn't work.

What works: instead of importing cols from another file, I added to the component and it works. So, when i have actual data in the component, it works.

Edit: Also tried returning object from a custom method but doesnt work. Also tried calling methods by declaring two variables but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A spread operator on the `cols` array would create a new array, but the references to the objects would remain the same, which is why you are seeing the changes upstream. You could use a spread operator inside of your map function instead:

```
return <Table
  cols={cols.map((col) => ({ ...col, Cell: (<SomeComponent />) })};
  data={[{}]}
/>
```

Note that this breaks down if your `col` object has more nested objects, in which case you may want to look into deep cloning.

Comment: Excellente! Deep cloning came out to be rescue. Thanks a ton!